# Remove partition for failed installation

Tags: installation, windows, partitioning, wubi

I tried installing ubuntu alongside windows 7

https://askubuntu.com/questions/77499/installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows

and I failed so I decided to go with wubi again. after installing it, I noticed a separate hard disk. I investigated and found out that this hard disk is actually for the failed installation.

I don't know where to find it inside the windows system. can anyone please teach me how to remove the 'failed' hard disk.

here's a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

the left side is the current filesystem. the right side on the other hand is the 'failed' harddisk. i verified that it is the failed one because the wubi installation will provide a 'host' folder for the current partition it is currently installed.

I tried looking for the 'failed' one using the windows' command-line but i don't know where to look for the 'failed' disk.

(I used the cmd coz I don't want root.disk to mysteriously disappear again.)

*see http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com/2011/01/mystery-of-disappearing-rootdisk.html*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot Windows and go to the Disk Management: click Start, type Disk Manage..., and select 'Create and format hard disk partitions'. There you'll see the 28GB Healthy Primary partition (with no filesystem shown - **so it won't show NTFS**).

To see what this looks like, check the highlighted partitions in the following picture:

[image: Disk Management console]

Just right click on the partition and select "Delete Volume". There'll probably also be a smaller one created for Swap. Then you might want to create a new NTFS partition in that space, or merge it back to an existing partition. Since the Ubuntu installer likely created an extended partition you'll have to delete that as well if you want to merge.

**Before deleting**: make double sure that you are not booting with the grub bootloader or your computer will not boot. It doesn't seem likely given your description, but you should check. Running the [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) is one way to tell. Another way is to check which menu you see when you boot.

If you're booting with Grub the first menu you see will look like this:
[image: Grub menu]

If you're booting with the windows boot loader (and you have Wubi installed), the first menu you see will be the windows boot manager:

[image: Windows boot manager]

To reinstall the Windows boot loader (Windows 7/Vista):

1. Boot Windows and create a Windows repair CD
2. Boot from the CD to a repair command prompt and run:

   `bootrec.exe /fixboot`
3. Make sure your computer boots straight into Windows (or the Windows boot manager)

However, since you wanted a normal dual boot, why don't you download and run the [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) and post the result to http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and then post the link back on your other question. That might be easily fixable. It might even already show up at the bottom of the Wubi grub menu.

Comment: how can i know if im booting with grub bootloader? sorry i did not get that part.

Comment: i see the windows boot loader first .so does this mean it is safe to just delete the partition?

Comment: If you see the windows boot manager first, then, yes, it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a wubi installation from Windows, open the control panel and select add/remove applications. Ubuntu will appear in the list of apps to uninstall.

When you use Wubi, it is very important that you always shutdown the system properly. Failing to do so might make the root filesystem inaccessible. This means both Windows and Ubuntu must always be properly shutdown.

Please refer to this page for more details: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: actually it is not a wubi installation i think see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/77499/installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows .it is done within the livecd not from the windows